# SSIS Result set, Foreachloop and Variable

Tags: sql, variables, ssis, resultset, foreach-loop-container

I'm having an issue and I don't know if this is possible to do.

I have a simple SQL task.

`SELECT Name, email FROM table_name`

Using a result set, I'm trying to pass it to a variable and use it on a email task with a foreach loop but i having no luck getting this to work. If I do just one column, it works fine. My issue is multiple columns.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Please detail how you have your Execute SQL Task set up, the Variables you have declared and their data types and how you have the ForEach loop configured

Comment: SQL is OLE DB with "Full Result set", Result Name 0, 1 mapped to two variable, User::email and user::Fullname. Both are "Object" data type.

Foreach loop is set to ADO Enumerator, Source variable set to User::email. 

but is failed on the SQL task when i add multiple column

Comment: What is the error you get? When I created similar query and assigned to two variables in result set, I got error in Execute SQL Task itself.

Comment: as soon I add the second variable the SQL task fail with no errors.

Answer (score 12):

I figured out my own question. I will add it here in case someone else have the same issue.

1. On the SQL query the first column should be your key result. for example mine was the email.
2. In the **SQL Task** under **General**, set **Resultset** to "Full Result rest"
3. In the **SQL Task** under **Result Set**, set variable with "0" as result name, create a variable as "Object" data type for the email column and click ok to save and exit. Example: email_Ob
4. By going to the **variable** window, create more variable for the other columns as Object and since I'm using this for email task I need to convert from Object to String, so I need to create another variable as string for each one

   Example:

   ```
          **Variable Name**       **Datatype**
              email_Ob                Object
              Name_Ob                 Object
              email_St                String
              Name_St                 String
   ```
5. **Foreach Loop task** Under **Collection** change the following:

   **Enumerator**: Foreach ADO Enomator

   **ADO object Source variable**: Select the key variable (email_Ob)

   Select **Rows in the first table**
6. **Foreach Loop task** under **Variable Mappings** add the variable with **String** data type the same order as on your SQL query. Click OK to save and exit.
7. Now you can add the **Email Task** inside **Foreach Loop** and use those String variable as part of the email or you can use it for any other task.

Hope this help and if you have any questions feel free to ask. Doing this way, I was able to add more columns as need it.

Comment: You only need one Object variable for your SQL task result set. Then you just that as your ADO Object Source Variable and map each of your resultset  columns by index to a variable (email_St, name_St), etc.

Comment: Error: The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::BaselineId" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.