# SSIS 2012 Full Result Set to set variables

Tags: ssis, foreach-loop-container

I'm trying to create an SSIS package that reads a mapping table that contains foreign key information and tables they point to and store the full result set to be used to populate 7 columns representing columns in the result set that is then used to update an xxxSID column on 6 servers.

I'm stuck!  Please help.

I've created the SQL Task with query to build the result set and mapped to object variable SidMap and the task runs successfully however, I don't know where to go from there.  Some blogs say create a ForEachLoop Container and map the object variable to the collection which I've done.  I've also created string variables representing the 7 columns but don't know how to populate them.

The blogs I've read so far suggest this can only be done from a Script task.  Is that true?  If so how is it done?

Another user posted a question that sounded like he may be doing the same or very similar thing using a SQL Task but I didn't see how he was populating the column object variables and then converting data into string variables.
[SSIS Result set, Foreachloop and Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643081/ssis-result-set-foreachloop-and-variable/23021491#23021491)

Currently I'm updating tables manually using a cursor.  If anyone cares to see the code I can post it but didn't think it relevant to the question other than providing a clear picture of what I'm doing.

Comment: Suggest that this would be better posted on the Database Administrators SE site

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a For Each Loop Container using the Foreach ADO Enumerator, and map the object variable to the collection.  I would map the 7 string variables on the Variable Mappings page.

This process is documented in detail here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879316.aspx

A common "gotcha" is mismatched datatypes between the result set and the Variables.  To avoid this I always wrap `CAST ( ... AS NVARCHAR ( 4000 ) )` or similar around the columns in the dataflow that produces the dataset, and all my receiving Variables are String datatype.